# Trim/Map a union of a specific function and a type T, as well as a standalone T to a function

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, conditional-types

Sorry for the complicated title, I couldn't think of a better one.

Additional context: This needs to work on TS 2.8.4

I need a little help with a mapping type

```
// Input types:
type FunctionOrObject<Arg, Result> =
| ((arg: Arg) => Partial<Result>)
| Partial<Result>;

interface ExampleArg {
  disabled: boolean;
}
interface ExampleResult {
  root: string;
  sub: string;
}

type FuncOrObj = FunctionOrObject<ExampleArg, ExampleResult>;
type Standalone = ExampleResult;

// Expected should have the type (arg: Arg) => Partial<Result>
type Expected = MagicMappingType<FuncOrObj >;

//  Expected2 should have the type (...args: any[]) => Partial<Result>
type Expected2 = MagicMappingType<Standalone>;
```

Right now I have come up with this, but it isn't working perfectly

```
type _TrimToFunction<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => any ? T : never;

// Expected has type (arg: ExampleArg) => Partial<ExampleResult> - Correct!
type Expected = _TrimToFunction<FuncOrObj>;

// Expected2 is never - Wrong!
type Expected2 = _TrimToFunction<Standalone>;
```

This obviously happens because the standalone interface `ExampleResult` does not pass the condition of `_TrimToFunction` and thus gets mapped to `never`. But if I change `_TrimToFunction` to this:

```
type _TrimToFunction<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => any ? T : (...args: any[]) => T;
```

mapping the standalone interface yields the correct result, but now I get a wrong result for the `FuncOrObj` type:

```
type Expected =
  | ((arg: ExampleArg) => Partial<ExampleResult>)
  | ((...args: any[]) => Partial<Partial<ExampleArg>>)

type Expected2 = (...args: any[]) => Partial<ExampleResult>
```

This is caused by the second part of the `FuncOrObj` union failing the condition check and getting mapped to the "else" type.

Is what I want to achieve even possible using TS 2.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get an unexpected type in your last snippet is that conditional types distribute over unions if the type parameter is naked. Read [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) for more info on this.

The simple solution is to change the condition a bit. We can use `Extract`. If we can extract a `Function` from `T` we return that, if we can't we return a new function returning `Partial<T>`

```
type _TrimToFunction<T> = Extract<T, Function> extends never ? (...args: any[]) => Partial<T>: Extract<T,Function>;

// Expected has type (arg: ExampleArg) => Partial<ExampleResult> - Correct!
type Expected3 = _TrimToFunction<FuncOrObj>;

// Expected2 is (...args: any[]) => Partial<ExampleResult>
type Expected4 = _TrimToFunction<Standalone>;
```

Comment: Thanks! I already knew that unions are distributed for conditional types, but it didn't come to my mind to simply use `Extract`. From what I can tell it's working, no failing tests.